# How to find the min and max element of an array list of big integers?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

How can I find the min and max element of an `ArrayList` of `BigIntegers`.

What I've tried is :

```
import java.math.BigInteger; 
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         BigInteger i1 = new BigInteger("4343345345345");
         BigInteger i2 = new BigInteger("4343453345345345");
         BigInteger i3 = new BigInteger("4343453345");

        List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(i1);
        list.add(i2);
        list.add(i3);

       BigInteger max = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);        

        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);

      System.out.println(max.intValue());
      System.out.println(min.intValue());
     }
}
```

But this gives me the following errors:

```
HelloWorld.java:20: error: ')' expected
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                    ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: ';' expected
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                     ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                      ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: ';' expected
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                       ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                        ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: ';' expected
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                                    ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: not a statement
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
                                                                                                     ^
HelloWorld.java:20: error: ';' expected
        BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(BigInteger::intValue())).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: `BigInteger` is naturally comparable. You should compare using [natural order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--). If your values are too big for ints then trying to compare with `intValue()` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         BigInteger i1 = new BigInteger("4343345345345");
         BigInteger i2 = new BigInteger("4343453345345345");
         BigInteger i3 = new BigInteger("22");

        List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(i1);
        list.add(i2);
        list.add(i3);


        System.out.println(Collections.min(list, Comparator.naturalOrder()));

     }
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `Collections.min(list)`

Answer (score 4):

Getting min and max does work without comparing `intValue`s. You should use the natural ordering:

```
BigInteger max = list.stream().max(BigInteger::compareTo).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);        
BigInteger min = list.stream().min(BigInteger::compareTo).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementExcep::new);
```

What also doesn't is the way, you're printing the values:

```
System.out.println(max.intValue());
System.out.println(min.intValue());
```

You're calling `intValue` method, but the number exceed the capacity of `int` (32b). You should rather use:

```
System.out.println(max);
System.out.println(min);
```

Comment: it gives the error: ```java:20: error: method max in interface Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        BigInteger max = list.stream().max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);       
                                      ^
  required: Comparator<? super BigInteger>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream```

Comment: Try `max(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: @khelwood I just corrected with `BigInteger`'s comparator but it's equivalent, thank you;)

Comment: I did it with ```naturalOrder()``` comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
BigInteger max = list.stream().max(BigInteger::compareTo).get();
BigInteger min = list.stream().min(BigInteger::compareTo).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger max = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(val -> new BigInteger(String.valueOf(val))))
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
BigInteger min = list.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(val -> new BigInteger(String.valueOf(val))))
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

---